# The REST Interface feature is not available in this Bugzilla

Tags: rest, bugzilla

I have installed Bugzilla 5.0.2 and tried accessing it through REST Api but I'm not able to access it.

I'm getting the following message.

"The REST Interface feature is not available in this Bugzilla."

I tried to access 
http://bugzillaserver/bugzilla/rest.cgi from the browser

But that also displays the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with optional perl modules.

Installed optional perl modules, now it is working fine.

Comment: This is not enough detail to understand what has to be done... can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The main module that cures this problem is `JSON::RPC (any) for the JSON-RPC interface`

Answer (score 0):

Same issue solved by
all SOAP,RCP related perl modules
and
ppm install Test-Taint
Perl version use ActivePerl-5.24.3.2404

Answer (score 0):

I already had `JSON::RPC` installed; the missing bit was `Test::Taint`, installed with `cpanm Test::Taint`.
It is also reported by `checksetup.pl` in this box:

```
***********************************************************************
* OPTIONAL MODULES                                                    *
***********************************************************************
* Certain Perl modules are not required by Bugzilla, but by           *
* installing the latest version you gain access to additional         *
* features.                                                           *
*                                                                     *
* The optional modules you do not have installed are listed below,    *
* with the name of the feature they enable. Below that table are the  *
* commands to install each module.                                    *
***********************************************************************
* MODULE NAME * ENABLES FEATURE(S)                                    *
***********************************************************************
*  ...                                                                *
*  Test-Taint * JSON-RPC Interface, XML-RPC Interface, REST Interface *
***********************************************************************
```